# Import an image as a background in Tkinter

Tags: python, image, import, tkinter, pygame

I've searched some other questions that many people did ask here about how can someone import an image as a background from Tkinter and I've got to say that I wasm't helped a lot.
Let me explain to you my problem. I have downloaded an image,converted it to gif and save it to my desktop.However can the Tkinter window opens up it does not import the image.
Here is my code:

```
import Tkinter as Tk
root = Tk.Tk()
background_image=Tk.PhotoImage("C:/Desktop/logo.gif")
background_label = Tk.Label(root, image=background_image)
background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
root.wm_geometry("600x400+20+40")
root.title('Menu')
playButton = Tk.Button(root, text='Play', command=root.destroy)
playButton.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Are you able to help me?

Comment: First, instead of saying "don't worry about the pygame module", just remove it from your post. Your post should include a [minimal, complete, valid example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem, not an arbitrary fragment of code that contains irrelevant stuff (or misses important stuff).

Comment: Second, using pygame and Tkinter together is probably not going to work the way you're expecting. There are ways you can do it—if only one or the other is running at any given time, or if you carefully weave the two event loops together, or if you use threads properly—but I'm guessing you weren't anticipating any of those, and are going to end up back on SO asking why your game freezes when you call `mainloop`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use PhotoImage in this way.

```
background_image=Tk.PhotoImage(file="C:/Desktop/logo.gif")
```